# serializer is not beeing used if included in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.default_includes = '**'
```

we render the comments via a serializer, including the author and some infos.

this is using the serializer and everything works great

```
render json: comments
```

however, we also need to send additional meta-data, so we wrap it into a hash. unfortunately this is not using the serializer and we can't figure out why

```
render json: {comments: comments, upvoted: upvoted, downvoted: downvoted}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `as_json`? Something like `render json: { comments: comments.as_json, upvoted: upvoted, downvoted: downvoted }`?

Comment: So you do have a comments serializer defined? Like an actual CommentsSerializer class?

Comment: @Gerry, has nothing to with with as_json or to_json as that'S done by default. just the lookup for the serializer was missing

Comment: @arjabbar yes indeed. as i said, the first line is working, just if its a hash it is not. problem figured out with this post https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2102#issuecomment-293292697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the git

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2102#issuecomment-293292697

it is not possible to automatically use a serializer if we render a hash, rather then a collection. the workaround is

```
json = Hash.new
json[:comments] = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(comments)
json[:upvoted] = upvoted
json[:downvoted] = downvoted
render status: :ok, json: json
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to have the upvoted and downvoted attributes included in the metadata. To include the upvoted and downvoted attributes as metadata you must use either the json or json_api adapters. Having this in your controller:

```
render json: comments, meta: { upvoted: upvoted, downvoted: downvoted }, adapter: :json
```

will render:

```
{
  "comments": [
    // your comments...
  ],
  "meta": {
    "upvoted": 4243,
    "downvoted": 123
  }
}
```

Either that or you could create a model just for this response which has the comments and the upvoted and downvoted attributes.

Comment: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2102#issuecomment-293292697

this i found., that's working

why we name additional fields `meta`in a json string? is there any convention for that?